# how can i get the pixels covered at every instance in sliding menu

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingmenu

I am using jfeinstein library in sliding menu and its working great. Now I just want to calculate the number of pixels which get covered while sliding it. I dont want the total width but the number of pixels which get covered at every instance.